# How to turn off ALL conventions in Entity Framework Core 5

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-5.0

I want to turn off **ALL** (or at least most of) conventions in Entity Framework Core (and I am talking about EF Core 5 or above) and then build the whole model "by hands".

**One may wonder why**.

**Here is why**: I have a task to migrate several large legacy databases from Entity Framework 6 (`EF`) to Entity Framework Core 5 (`EFC`). This involves many hundreds of tables and several databases. Some of these databases are created using a Code First approach and some are just third party databases, which we need to query and update from C# code. For the latter databases we must match their schema exactly.

Due to the size of the problem both `EF` and `EFC` flavors of the code must coexist for, let's say, several months. This can be easily achieved by using conditional compilation (see below).

Most likely anything that is not supported or is inconveniently supported in `EFC` in comparison to `EF` (or was "hacked" into `EF` models), like spatial indexes, multi-column `KeyAttribute` PKs, multi-column `ForeignKeyAttribute` FKs, self-referencing multiple times tables, multiple indexes defined on the same columns (some are filters and some are just regular indexes), and so on and so forth is there.

That's fine. I can easily deal with `EFC` **inability** to deal with that by "overriding" the attributes using conditional compilation, e.g.

```
#if EFCORE
using Key = MyKeyAttribute;
using Column = MyColumnAttribute;
using Index = MyIndexAttribute;
using ForeignKey = MyForeignKeyAttribute;
#endif
```

then for each `MyProject.csproj` create a `MyProject_EFC.csproj` where `EFCORE` is defined, then use Reflection to "collect" all these custom attributes, and then use `EFC` Fluent API to configure all that stuff that `EFC` can't do. So, the legacy (`EF`) code will still see the originals, e.g. `KeyAttribute` and then follow the `EF` route, whereas the `EFC` code won't see the attributes because they were redefined. And so, it won't complain. ***I already have all that code, it works and, perhaps, I will put it here or in GitHub at some point, but not today***.

What drives me nuts is that no matter what I do, `EFC` manages to "sneak in" shadow properties and similar crappy things. This gets to the point that I really want to turn off **ALL** `EFC` conventions and build the whole model by hands. After all, I am already doing that, like for the 90% of the model. I would rather want `EFC` throw (with a meaningful error message) than silently do anything that I don't expect it to do.

Following the advice of @IvanStoev here is what I currently have:

```
public static IModel CreateModel<TContext, TContextInfo>(Action<ModelBuilder, TContextInfo>? modifier = null)
    where TContext : DbContext, ISwyfftDbContext
    where TContextInfo : ContextInfo<TContext>, new()
{
    var contextInfo = new TContextInfo();
    var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();

    modelBuilder
        .HasKeys<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .HasColumnNames<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .ToTables<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .DisableCascadeDeletes()
        .HasDefaultValues<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .HasComputedColumns<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .HasForeignKeys<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo)
        .HasDatabaseIndexes<TContext, TContextInfo>(contextInfo);

    modifier?.Invoke(modelBuilder, contextInfo);
    var model = modelBuilder.FinalizeRelationalModel();
    return model;
}

private static IModel FinalizeRelationalModel(this ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    var model = modelBuilder.Model;
    var conventionModel = model as IConventionModel;
    var databaseModel = new RelationalModel(model);
    conventionModel.SetAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.RelationalModel, databaseModel);
    return modelBuilder.FinalizeModel();
}
```

where `HasKeys`, `HasColumnNames`, etc. are extension methods that I wrote [earlier] to keep using multi-column PKs, Fs, etc., which are not supported by `EFC` and `conventionModel.SetAnnotation(RelationalAnnotationNames.RelationalModel, databaseModel)` is mandatory as otherwise the model is not created and the code fails with NRE.

So, when I stick in this `CreateModel` into `DbContextOptions`:

```
public static DbContextOptions<TContext> GetDbContextOptions(string connectionString, Func<IModel> modelCreator) =>
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>()
        .UseModel(modelCreator())
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
        .Options;
```

and create a migration by running e.g. `Add-Migration Initial` then `ModelSnapshot` finally comes out correct with no garbage shadow properties, and no other crap that `EFC` with all conventions inserts here or there. However, when I try to query any table, the code fails with:

```
(InvalidOperationException) Sequence contains no elements; 
Sequence contains no elements (   at System.Linq.ThrowHelper.ThrowNoElementsException()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Single[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressions.SelectExpression..ctor(IEntityType entityType, ISqlExpressionFactory sqlExpressionFactory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.SqlExpressionFactory.Select(IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.CreateShapedQueryExpression(IEntityType entityType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitExtension(Expression extensionExpression)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.Expression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ToQueryString(IQueryable source)
```

which means that the `RelationalModel` is severely incomplete.

Any *further* ideas will be highly appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible by building the [`IModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.imodel?view=efcore-5.0) by hand

```
static IModel CreateModel(/* args */)
{
    var modelBuilder = new ModelBuilder();
    // Build the model using the modelBuilder
    // ...
    return modelBuilder.FinalizeModel();
}
```

The essential here is the usage of the parameterless [`ModelBuilder()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.modelbuilder.-ctor?view=efcore-5.0#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_ModelBuilder__ctor) constructor which

> Initializes a new instance of the `ModelBuilder` class with no conventions

Then you associate it with the context using the [`UseModel`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontextoptionsbuilder.usemodel?view=efcore-5.0) method, for instance inside the target context `OnConfiguring` override

```
optionsBuilder.UseModel(CreateModel())
```

With this approach, `OnModelCreating` of the target context is not used.

This should achieve what you are asked for. But beware of the warning for the used `ModelBuilder` constructor:

> Warning: conventions are typically needed to build a correct model.

So you must be very careful to map everything explicitly. From the other side, the exact same approach is used internally by EF Core migrations (the generated method `BuildTargetModel` inside `.designer.cs` file) to generate model at point where the classes might not exist or could be totally different, so it should be a viable option when used properly.

---

**Update:** It turns out that *"conventions are typically needed to build a correct model"* in the warning really means that conventions (at least some of them) are really *mandatory* for building correct runtime model, because they are used to perform some actions which control the runtime behaviors.

Most noticeable are `RelationalModelConvention` which creates the relational model (tables, columns etc.) mappings, and `TypeMappingConvention` which creates provider data type mappings. Hence these two are mandatory. But who knows, there could be more. And extensions are allowed to add their own.

So before reading further, consider using the standard approach with all conventions. Seriously. Fluent configuration has higher priority (conventions < data annotations < fluent (explicit)), so if you explicitly configure everything, you shouldn't be getting unexpected shadow, discriminator etc. property issues.

Now, if you want to continue the dangerous path, you should create the minimal conventions needed, or even better, remove the not needed conventions which are causing you problems. The public EF Core 5.x way of modifying conventions is to register custom [`IConventionSetPlugin`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.metadata.conventions.infrastructure.iconventionsetplugin?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure.IConventionSetPlugin);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=efcore-5.0) implementation which has single method

> ```
> public ConventionSet ModifyConventions (ConventionSet conventionSet);
> ```

which allows you to modify (replace, add new, remove) the default conventions, or even return a brand new convention set.

Registering such plugin is not so easy and requires a bunch of plumbing (even though boilerplate) code. But it is preferred because it allows you to remove specific conventions (just note that the convention class can implement several convention related interfaces, so it must be removed from several `ConventionSet` lists), and also the mandatory convention classes have additional dependencies and use DI container for resolving them, so it's not easy (if not impossible) to create them from outside.

With that being said, here is a sample implementation which removes all conventions, keeping only the ones registered in `ModelFinalizingConventions` and `ModelFinalizedConventions` which seems to be essential for building properly functioning runtime model:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Infrastructure
{
    public class CustomConventionSetPlugin : IConventionSetPlugin
    {
        public ConventionSet ModifyConventions(ConventionSet conventionSet)
        {
            conventionSet.EntityTypeAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.EntityTypeAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.EntityTypeBaseTypeChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.EntityTypeIgnoredConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.EntityTypeMemberIgnoredConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.EntityTypePrimaryKeyChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ForeignKeyAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ForeignKeyAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ForeignKeyDependentRequirednessChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ForeignKeyRequirednessChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ForeignKeyUniquenessChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.IndexAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.IndexAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.IndexRemovedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.IndexUniquenessChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.KeyAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.KeyAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.KeyRemovedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ModelAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            //conventionSet.ModelFinalizedConventions.Clear();
            //conventionSet.ModelFinalizingConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.ModelInitializedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.NavigationAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.NavigationAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.NavigationRemovedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.PropertyAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.PropertyAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.PropertyFieldChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.PropertyNullabilityChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.PropertyRemovedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.SkipNavigationAddedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.SkipNavigationAnnotationChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.SkipNavigationForeignKeyChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.SkipNavigationInverseChangedConventions.Clear();
            conventionSet.SkipNavigationRemovedConventions.Clear();
            return conventionSet;
        }
    }
}

// Boilerplate for regigistering the plugin

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure
{
    public class CustomConventionSetOptionsExtension : IDbContextOptionsExtension
    {
        public CustomConventionSetOptionsExtension() { }
        ExtensionInfo info;
        public DbContextOptionsExtensionInfo Info => info ?? (info = new ExtensionInfo(this));
        public void Validate(IDbContextOptions options) { }
        public void ApplyServices(IServiceCollection services)
            => services.AddSingleton<IConventionSetPlugin, CustomConventionSetPlugin>();
        sealed class ExtensionInfo : DbContextOptionsExtensionInfo
        {
            public ExtensionInfo(CustomConventionSetOptionsExtension extension) : base(extension) { }
            public override bool IsDatabaseProvider => false;
            public override string LogFragment => string.Empty;
            public override void PopulateDebugInfo(IDictionary<string, string> debugInfo) { }
            public override long GetServiceProviderHashCode() => 1234;
        }
    }
}

namespace Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
{
    public static partial class CustomDbContextOptionsExtensions
    {
        public static DbContextOptionsBuilder UseCustomConventionSet(this DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            if (optionsBuilder.Options.FindExtension<CustomConventionSetOptionsExtension>() == null)
                ((IDbContextOptionsBuilderInfrastructure)optionsBuilder).AddOrUpdateExtension(new CustomConventionSetOptionsExtension());
            return optionsBuilder;
        }
    }
}
```

It provides a convenient `Use` extension method similar to other extensions, so all you need is to call it during the configuration, e.g. in `OnConfiguring` override

```
optionsBuilder.UseCustomConventionSet();
```

or with your example

```
public static DbContextOptions<TContext> GetDbContextOptions(string connectionString, Func<IModel> modelCreator) =>
    new DbContextOptionsBuilder<TContext>()
        .UseSqlServer(connectionString, x => x.UseNetTopologySuite())
        .UseCustomConventionSet()
        .Options;
```

`OnConfiguring` is preferred though, since this has nothing to do with database provider, and also does not use external model creation (and `UseModel`) as with the original suggestion - the fluent configuration goes back to `OnModelCreating` override.

Comment: Thanks. I will give it a try and advise about the results in a few days.

Comment: I updated the question. The `RelationalModel` is incomplete but `ModelSnapshot` finally came out correct. Do you have any ideas what to do with `RelationalModel`? Thanks.

Comment: @KonstantinKonstantinov See the update. Couldn't find more reliable way, and even the suggested is not guaranteed to work. But at least (tested) it allows executing queries, which wasn't possible with the original as well as with your relational model additions.

Comment: Another convention that must be kept is `EntityTypeAddedConventions`. EFC cannot translate `byte[]` data type without it. There is also `PropertyAnnotationChangedConventions`, which is responsible for adding identity to a non-PK column. However it also adds `IsRequired` for all `string` (not `string?`) properties and this is wrong. So, I ended up keeping just 4 conventions. I also used `.ReplaceService<IProviderConventionSetBuilder, EmptyCustomSetBuilder>()` where `EmptyCustomSetBuilder : SqlServerConventionSetBuilder` overrides `CreateConventionSet` and clears all unneeded conventions.

Comment: That's another way. But didn't suggest it because it is marked as internal and more importantly, bound to SqlServer provider, while the plugin approach is database agnostic. What about which conventions to keep, I already wrote my opinion to "keep them all" :) Or remove just some you really know are not needed.

Comment: Ivan, thank a lot! It turned out that removing all but 4 conventions (as discussed above) is nearly mandatory when dealing with third party databases and I could "get away with" just removing a part of FK conventions when dealing with EF created databases. And since we are only dealing with Azure MSSQL databases, I am OK with using only SqlServer provider. Nevertheless, I will try rewriting the code using your ideas and I will advise how it works in due course.

Comment: How did they make it *THIS* complicated to simply disable all of their wonderful conventions? You're a life saver, I've been looking for this for days. Thanks.