# EF Core : Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a PassengerConfigurations class to map my entity to database. When I use dotnet ef migration I got an error  System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

The stack trace is indicating a NullReferenceException specifically related to a foreign key relationship between Passenger and FlightTicket.

```
...

namespace Ceyehat.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configurations;

public class PassengerConfigurations : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Passenger>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Passenger> builder)
    {
        ConfigurePassengersTable(builder);
        ConfigurePassengerFlightTicketsTable(builder);
    }

    private void ConfigurePassengerFlightTicketsTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Passenger> builder)
    {
        builder.OwnsMany(
            p => p.FlightTicketIds,
            ftb =>
            {
                ftb.ToTable("PassengerFlightTickets");
                
                ftb.HasKey(ft => ft.Id);
                
                ftb.Property(ft => ft.Id)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasConversion(
                        ft => ft.Value,
                        value => FlightTicketId.Create(value));
                
                ftb.Property(ft => ft.FlightId)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasConversion(
                        ft => ft.Value,
                        value => FlightId.Create(value));

                ftb.Property(ft => ft.SeatId)
                    .ValueGeneratedNever()
                    .HasConversion(
                        ft => ft.Value,
                        value => SeatId.Create(value));

                ftb.OwnsOne(ft => ft.BoardingPass, bp =>
                {
                    bp.ToTable("PassengerBoardingPasses");
                    
                    bp.HasKey(b => b.Id);
                    
                    bp.Property(b => b.Id)
                        .ValueGeneratedNever()
                        .HasConversion(
                            b => b.Value,
                            value => BoardingPassId.Create(value));

                    bp.Property(b => b.Gate)
                        .HasMaxLength(8);
                    
                    bp.Property(b => b.BoardingTime)
                        .IsRequired();
                });
            });
        
        builder.Metadata.FindNavigation(nameof(Passenger.FlightTicketIds))!
            .SetPropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.Field);
    }

    private void ConfigurePassengersTable(EntityTypeBuilder<Passenger> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Passengers");
        
        builder.HasKey(p => p.Id);
        
        builder.Property(p => p.Id)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                p => p.Value,
                value => PassengerId.Create(value));
        
        builder.Property(p => p.CustomerId)
            .ValueGeneratedNever()
            .HasConversion(
                p => p.Value,
                value => CustomerId.Create(value));
    }
}
```

I traced the stack provided on my terminal and find out there's a error in builder.OwnsMany() block in ConfigurePassengerFlightTicketsTable method.

I mapped 9 other entities without errors. But this one is not accepting.

Exception Details

```
Build started...
Build succeeded.
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
 ---> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionBatchExtensions.Run(IConventionBatch batch, InternalForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Internal.InternalForeignKeyBuilder.ReuniquifyImplicitProperties(Boolean force)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.DiscoverProperties(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.ForeignKeyPropertyDiscoveryConvention.ProcessForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder, IConventionContext`1 context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ImmediateConventionScope.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChanged(IConventionForeignKeyBuilder relationshipBuilder)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.OnForeignKeyRequirednessChangedNode.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.DelayedConventionScope.Run(ConventionDispatcher dispatcher)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Conventions.Internal.ConventionDispatcher.ConventionBatch.Run(IConventionForeignKey foreignKey)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsManyBuilder[TRelatedEntity](TypeIdentity ownedType, MemberIdentity navigation)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.Builders.EntityTypeBuilder`1.OwnsMany[TRelatedEntity](Expression`1 navigationExpression, Action`1 buildAction)
   at Ceyehat.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configurations.PassengerConfigurations.ConfigurePassengerFlightTicketsTable(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in /Users/ademclk/RiderProjects/ceyehat-api/Ceyehat.Infrastructure/Persistence/Configurations/PassengerConfigurations.cs:line 21
   at Ceyehat.Infrastructure.Persistence.Configurations.PassengerConfigurations.Configure(EntityTypeBuilder`1 builder) in /Users/ademclk/RiderProjects/ceyehat-api/Ceyehat.Infrastructure/Persistence/Configurations/PassengerConfigurations.cs:line 16
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration[TEntity](IEntityTypeConfiguration`1 configuration)
   at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Void** arguments, Signature sig, Boolean isConstructor)
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Reflection.MethodInvoker.Invoke(Object obj, IntPtr* args, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ModelBuilder.ApplyConfigurationsFromAssembly(Assembly assembly, Func`2 predicate)
   at Ceyehat.Infrastructure.Persistence.CeyehatDbContext.OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) in /Users/ademclk/RiderProjects/ceyehat-api/Ceyehat.Infrastructure/Persistence/CeyehatDbContext.cs:line 35
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelCustomizer.Customize(ModelBuilder modelBuilder, DbContext context)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.CreateModel(DbContext context, IConventionSetBuilder conventionSetBuilder, ModelDependencies modelDependencies)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.ModelSource.GetModel(DbContext context, ModelCreationDependencies modelCreationDependencies, Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.CreateModel(Boolean designTime)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.DbContextServices.get_Model()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.EntityFrameworkServicesBuilder.<>c.<TryAddCoreServices>b__8_4(IServiceProvider p)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<RealizeService>b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(Type serviceType, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService[T](IServiceProvider provider)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_ContextServices()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.IInfrastructure<System.IServiceProvider>.get_Instance()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.InfrastructureExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.AccessorExtensions.GetService[TService](IInfrastructure`1 accessor)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(Func`1 factory)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.DbContextOperations.CreateContext(String contextType)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.Internal.MigrationsOperations.AddMigration(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigrationImpl(String name, String outputDir, String contextType, String namespace)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.<>c__DisplayClass3_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationExecutor.OperationBase.Execute(Action action)
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

Comment: Post the full exception details, including the stack trace, in the question itself. We can't guess where the error was thrown. You can easily copy the full details if you click on `Copy Details` in the exception popup, if you call `Exception.ToString()` or log the full exception object

Comment: What are all those `FlightTicketId.Create`s? Are you sure it's not those methods that throw? Why is there a conversion on every single key property?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I added the exception details. Those are from my aggregate roots to map them on database I should convert them first.

Comment: The error is thrown when applying migrations. `...OperationExecutor.AddMigration.<>c__DisplayClass0_0.<`. If those `Create` methods try to use the database to generate keys, they'll fail if the wrong database is used

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos to prevent this I map them ValueGeneratedNever. They are uuids on my database. I'm using postgresql.

Comment: You're trying to mix things that concern different levels. There are no aggregate roots in ORMs, even if ORMs can be used to load entire object graphs in a single query. You're trying to use DDD concepts at the wrong level. Using GUIDs as keys is already supported without requiring extra classes, even though it's a bad idea resulting in table fragmentation and losing the ability to execute range queries on keys. The primary reason people use GUIDs as keys is to avoid contacting the database to get db-generated keys

Comment: The [docs on Primary Key value generation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/generated-properties?tabs=data-annotations#primary-keys) say: `By convention, non-composite primary keys of type short, int, long, or Guid are set up to have values generated for inserted entities if a value isn't provided by the application`. You shouldn't have to configure anything.

Comment: Anyway, the call stack shows that the problem is caused when the model builder tries to discover metadata properties for foreign keys so it can apply conventions to them. If you use types that EF Core knows nothing about, that will fail. Without knowing what those custom types are, one can only say that you have to disable conventions and configure those that apply yourself. [This SO question may help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67746656/how-to-turn-off-all-conventions-in-entity-framework-core-5)

Comment: Also check [Value Objects as Keys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions?tabs=data-annotations#value-objects-as-keys) in the docs. Notice the warnings too